# How to limit Vd and Vq in FOC for 3kW , 48VAC induction motor?

Tags: motor-controller, induction-motor, encoder, vector-control

I am working on developing motor controller for AC Induction Motor.Following are the specifications of the motor:

Rated voltage:**48VAC**
Rated power : **3kW**
Rated current :**54A**
Poles : **4**
Position feedback : **Encoder**.

Following are the specifications of my controller:

Algorithm : **FOC using encoder**.
DC Link Voltage : **82 MAX , 72 Rated , 65 MIN**
Drive Mode : **Speed Mode**

When my inverter is operating at the state when I'm giving 100% duty for operation , AC voltage may go beyond rated voltage of the motor and may damage the windings of the motor.

How can we regulate **Vd and Vq** in software so that maximum output AC voltage is capped at **48VAC** ?

Comment: keep the duty cycle less than 100%...

Comment: The peak voltage shouldn’t be an issue for the motor windings as the insulation should be good for much more than 48Vac. What you do need to concern yourself with is the average energy you’re feeding the motor as this will affect the temperature of the motor and windings. This is specified as RMS torque. As mentioned, your duty cycle affects the amount of energy.